# Broken bottom bracket

Tags: mountain-bike, bottom-bracket

When applying pressure to my bike to go faster to maintain a speed, my bike aggressively ticks and doesn’t run smoothly. Could this be the bottom bracket?

Comment: Sounds to me like the chain is skipping on the cogs.  Likely the chain is worn beyond its limit, and it may be that some of the cogs are worn out as well.

Answer (score 5):

**Possibly** yes it could be the bottom bracket making periodic noises.

Can also be pedals, chain sticky links, bent chainring, damaged teeth on chainring, alignment of front mech.  Crack in frame, damaged seat, damaged seatpost clamp, or damaged saddle rails clamp.

One elimination technique is to figure out if the noise is timed with crank rotations, or with wheel rotations.  IE does the noise change frequency when you're in a different gear, or does its frequency relate to road speed ?

Also try pedalling backward and see if the problem noise changes in any way.

Can you also eliminate handlebars by pedalling hard while varying grip locations - even hold the stem with alternate hands to eliminate other areas of cause.  Then check the rear derailleur and mech, jockey wheels and cassette for anything blocking.

"periodic sounds" are very hard to diagnose.  Did you crash recently?  Has someone vandalised your bike?   Has any part been changed recently?  Did you loan your bike to someone ?

Comment: Probably more of a comment than an answer, but too long.  If OP comes back with more info then better answers will be forthcoming.

Comment: Why do people *always* assume it's the bottom bracket?